# Loading AngularJS app within KnockoutJS app as iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, knockout.js

I have got a requirement to show an already developed AngualarJS web app into another web app which is developed using KnockoutJS and JQuery. The parent app which is developed using pure knockoutJS templates technique. I did some investigation on this and found iFrame as one approach to acheive this(don't know whether it is right approach). I did a prototype where I loaded AngularJs app within iFrame which is declared parent app's template files. 
At proptotype level, it worked fine. But, I am facing some issues here 
a) I have to declare iFrame in all the Parent's(KnockoutJS app) template files.
b) The communication between iFrame and Parent web page/app(both app will be in same domain) looks bit complex and unreliable.

Could anybody suggest me some better approach to achieve this ?

Thanks,
bms

Answer (score 2):

Actually, ko can play nicely with angular. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jB2Qk/20/) we have both angular and ko  applied to the same page, with ko controlling a part of the dom, and angular another. They can talk to each other too.

The only special thing is a custom binding which tells ko not to control the dom branch which belongs to angular. With this approach, you don't need an iframe.
But probably you'll still have to change the ko templates. I don't know angular very well, so the angular code might be very bad.

html:

```
<div>
   <div>message for angular:<input type="text" data-bind="value:data"/>
      <button data-bind="click:sendDataToAng">send message to angular</button>
   </div>
   <span data-bind="text:externalMessage"></span>
</div>

<div data-bind="noControl:{}">
<div >
<hr />
<div>--------------Angular section, everything outside horizontal lines is controlled by ko------------</div>
<div ng-app="" >
   <div ng-controller="ngvm.Cntl" id="angularContainer" >
      message for ko: <input type="text" ng-model="data" />      
      <button type='button' ng-click="sendToKO()"> send message to ko </button>
      <div ng-bind="externalMessage"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<hr />    
    </div>
</div>

    someValue: <input data-bind="value:someValue, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />    
<div data-bind="text:someValue">
</div>
```

js, nowrap -- in head, for angular to work:

```
var ngvm = {
    Cntl: function($scope) {
        $scope.data = '';
        $scope.sendToKO = function(){            
            console.log($scope.data);
            kovm.externalMessage("message from angular: " + $scope.data);
        }
        $scope.externalMessage = "no extsdfernal messages";


        $scope.$watch('externalMessage', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        });        
    }
}

$(function(){
    var KOCtor = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.externalMessage = ko.observable("no external messages");
        self.data = ko.observable();
        self.sendDataToAng = function(){
        var $scope = angular.element($("#angularContainer")[0]).scope();            
            $scope.$apply(function(){                
                $scope.externalMessage = "message from ko: " + self.data();
            });    
            $scope.$digest();
        }


        self.someValue = ko.observable("koko");
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.noControl = {
       init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){         
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };              
    },
    update:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){                               
    }        
    }

   window.kovm = new KOCtor();    
   ko.applyBindings(window.kovm);
})
```